# CS50 Mario Prompt: No such file or directory

Tags: cs50

When trying to run Mario (~/pset1/mario/ $ ./mario) in the terminal the response in return is "bash: ./mario: No such file or directory". I've tried fixing several times making sure I created the directory correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run make mario first?
[You should have 2 files in your ide for mario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mmei.png)
After running `make mario`, you can run `./mario`

Comment: thanks for your response. yes i did run make mario first.